# Multiline modal-header in Bootstrap 4/5

Tags: bootstrap-modal

In Bootstrap v3 I was able to create a multiline modal-header in dialogs, to place a little bit of user help at the top, such as:

```
   <div class="modal fade" id="fileOpenModal" role="dialog" tabindex='-1'>
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header" style="margin-bottom:4px">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Open a File</h4>
                    <p style="font-family:Arial; font-size:12px; font-style:italic;margin-bottom:0px">Open an existing file for editing. Current open files will not be closed.</p>
                 </div>
                 <div class="modal-body">
            .... etc.
```

I've tried all sorts of combinations in Bootstrap 5 but cannot seem to get the same functionality.

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this by turning off the flexbox for the header and forcing `display:block`:

> ```
>     .modal-header {
>         display: block;
>         padding: 1rem 1rem;
>         border-bottom: 1px solid #dee2e6;
>         border-top-left-radius: calc(.3rem - 1px);
>         border-top-right-radius: calc(.3rem - 1px);
>     }
> ```